# Search and verify contact number on Server

Tags: android, telephonymanager

In my app i'm passing my all contacts to my server to verify if given number is registered or not.

Issue is number can be saved in any of following manner

*+91 9619*

*9619*

*09619*

Basically all are same, where should I do the validation on my php script or in native, if in native, how?

Guidance needed , Thanks

Comment: You have ti manage this from php side by using like query, for that you need to choose first one format like with "+91", "0" or without any prefix and then you can use like query

Comment: @Vickyexpert I have handled **0** from my side

Comment: @Vickyexpert number can be of different country how should I manage that?

Comment: you have to use like query and send only number without any prefix so now by like query it will retunr the number with prefix or without prefix, just it should have valid number

Answer (score 1):

Use only last 10 digits 9619****** while searching for numbers ...

Eg :
if +91 9619123456 is already registered and 9619123456 or 09619123456 is sent to server last 10 digits of all 3 number are same so the will be verified as register ..

Use **substr($my_string, -10)** to get last 10 digits of phone number

Comment: every country's number can't be 10 digits

Answer (score 0):

In your db query write like this

String combination1="original number"

String combination2="remove first digit in original number"

String combination3="remove first 2 digits in original number"

Query:

select count(*)

from table_name

where phoneNumer="combination1" or phoneNumer="combination2" or phoneNumer="combination3"

Example:
  If you pass 0997568474 the query is like this

select count(*)

from table_name

where phoneNumer="0997568474" or phoneNumer="997568474" or phoneNumer="97568474"

if count is greater than zero that means phone number existed...